# How to insert data on array multidimensional in PHP 7

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

I have PHP array multidimensional code like bellow :

```
$tabel = array(
    "K1" => array(
        'biaya' => '3',
        'gangguan' => ''
    ),
    "K2" => array(
        'biaya' => '3',
        'gangguan' => '',
    ),
);
```

how to insert data on `gangguan` using manual syntax with php?

Comment: `$table["K1"]["gangguan"] = $value`... next time don't hesitate to use Google first

Comment: `$table['K1']['gangguan'] = 'your text';`